# How to extract symbolic links with minizip library

Tags: c, zip, unzip

Is there any way how to correctly extract symbolic links via [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) library on OS X?

When extracting file via

```
 status = mz_zip_reader_extract_to_file(&zip_archive, i, output_path, 0);
```

it's created text file instead of symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that minizip doesn't handle symbolic links at all.

The only way I have found is do it completely our self. Snippet of logic:

```
mz_zip_archive_file_stat file_stat;
mz_zip_reader_file_stat(&zip_archive, i, &file_stat);
mz_uint32 attrFs = file_stat.m_external_attr >> 16;
if ( S_ISLNK(attrFs) )
{
  //read text file with link destination
  mz_zip_reader_extract_to_mem(&zip_archive, i, (void*)buffer, file_stat.m_uncomp_size, 0) )
  ...
  //create symbolic link manually
  boost::filesystem::create_symlink(...);
}
```

in case of Windows system it's necessary to define S_ISLNK based on Unix equivalent, becase `S_ISLNK` isn't defined for Windows.